# The woman between the two pillars

Tags: riddle

Last night I had a dream:

> I beheld a woman with a scroll in her hand
>   And the crescent moon beneath her feet,
>   And she sat between two pillars
>   Whose names are B. and J.
>   And she said, "There are others
>   Who are like me, but I trump them all."

Who can interpret the dream, and tell me the name of the woman whom I saw, and the scroll which was in her hand, and the two pillars between which she was seated?

Comment: On reading the answer to the riddle, I was disappointed that the answer was so literal (though "trump" is a clever twist of words). I had thought the first few lines were some clever metaphor or wordplay, but they are really just describing the thing. I feel like solving this is mostly about knowing or recognizing the relevant image.

Comment: I see your point. But to be fair, there are many different Tarot decks with different illustrations, e.g. some decks might not show the letters B and J on the pillars, or some decks might show a book instead of a scroll, etc.

@d'alar'cop mentions in his answer that he was able to solve it quickly was because he already knew the names of the pillars B and J.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

She is:

> [The High Priestess (of the Tarot)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_High_Priestess)

**Explanation**

I beheld a woman with a scroll in her hand

> In her card in the Tarot she is holding a scroll.

And the crescent moon beneath her feet,

> In her card in the Tarot she has a crescent moon at her feet.

And she sat between two pillars Whose names are B. and J.

> I cracked it because I thought of [Boaz and Jachin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boaz_and_Jachin#In_popular_media) immediately. From the link: *"The woman sat like that blind interlocutrix between Boaz and Jachin inscribed upon the one card in the juggler's deck that they would not see come to light, true pillars and true card,prophetess for all."*

And she said, "There are others Who are like me, but I trump them all."

> According to [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_High_Priestess): The High Priestess is the second trump or Major Arcana card in most traditional Tarot decks. This card is used in game playing as well as in divination. In the first Tarot pack with inscriptions, the 18th-century woodcut Marseilles Tarot, this figure is crowned with the Papal tiara and labelled La Papesse, the Popess, a possible reference to the legend of Pope Joan.

[See a cool image depicting your dream](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/88/RWS_Tarot_02_High_Priestess.jpg)

Comment: Well done. You found exactly the picture I was thinking of!

Comment: @jackvsworld lucky I knew about Boaz and Jachin! :D

Answer (score 4):

> Last night you had a dream   
>  'twas me you'd seen  
>   [image] 
>  Lady Justice is I, and  
>  the scroll in my hand 
>  was the law of your land 
>  Nestled in my crescent wreath  
>  It is this I do bequeath 
>  The pillars of **J**ustice   
> are mine alone  
> How the **B**alance swings  
> is yours to have known 
>  Be warned that others  
> will lead you astray    
> and that only I   
> will have the last say

Comment: you should write riddles!

Comment: +1 Not exactly the woman in my dream, but still a very good answer!

Comment: @d'alar'cop - [I did that once](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10559/defeat-by-me-your-destiny). It took three years for someone to answer it.